# Trying to understand why .apply is necessary when implementing underscore's invoke function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement Underscore JS's _.invoke function. Here is what it's supposed to do: Calls the method named by methodName on each value in the list. Any extra arguments passed to invoke will be forwarded on to the method invocation.

And here is the implementation:

```
    _.invoke = function(list, methodName, arguments) {
      return _.map(collection, function(item){
        if (typeof methodName === 'string'){
          return item[methodName](arguments);
        } else {
          return methodName.apply(item, arguments);
        }
      });  
   };
```

I am currently learning about the .call and .apply methods and don't understand why I need to use .apply in this case. What's the difference between using apply and simply writing `return functionOrKey(item, args)` ?

Comment: First of all, using `arguments` as a parameter/variable name is invalid in strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) sets the value of `this` within the invoked function. So writing

```
methodName.apply(item, arguments);
```

is the same as

```
item.methodName(argument1, argument2 /*, ...*/);
```

If `item` doesn't have a method `methodName` but you want to use `methodName` as if it were a property of `item`, then you need to use `apply` (or `call` if you know what each argument is) as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is context. call/apply allows you to specify what 'this' is in the called function.

```
methodName.apply(item, arguments);
```

runs methodName with this=item, where

```
return functionOrKey(item, args)
```

uses the current context in the invoke function as 'this'